# Bootstrap 3 Make navigational arrows on left and right of screen

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

IS there a simple way to use Bootstrap 3 to float two navigational arrows on the left and right of the page. Basically a forward and back button... I want the buttons to float, I want them to stay centered on the page horizontally and not overlap any of the content on my page.

Basically, I want the entire page to work like an image carousel...I just don't have images.

I also have use of Angular 1.3 for this task if I need it.

I essentially just want a CSS snippet that will put a left arrow on the left of my screen and a right arrow on the right and float and keep them there... The nagivation will be handled by angular routing... I am just trying to get a simple display css...

Comment: If you are using angular, why not check out angular bootstrap ui? They have a carousel there: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I don't want a carousel... and I didn't really want to dig through the carousel code to attempt to backport it just to add a left and right button on my screen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, for a boostrap navigational arrows,

Make a link anchor that has the same height as the page holding your information, as you have the same height, the arrow will be in the center of your anchor tag:

So on the left side it will look like this:

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#/current/prev" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
```

on the right side of your page, it will look like this:

```
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#/current/next" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

The middle page will be the content that you will be switching and routing using angular.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkbywbv1/2/

From there you can play around with the carousel-control css styling to fit your needs.

Comment: I am already using angular routes and the left and right arrows will just call methods to change the route already... I'm looking for a simple CSS trick, not the logic for the routing...